# C# - Silverlight - ItemControl, conditional item template

Tags: c#, silverlight, data-binding

I have an item controller which I bind to `ObservableCollection<User>`.
I ran into an issue where when there is only one user I would like to show a different `ItemTemplate` (just the Rating for example - and use default for everything else) and if there are more I would like to let people edit a bit more about them - combo box etc.

I though that probably there is a way of using converter for this, however I'm not sure how I can use converter to pick either one or another. So far I have managed to write a converter to hide/show **two** separate `ItemControl`s dependable on `Count` of `ObservableCollection<User> property`. However, I don't think this is the best way of solving this problem.

Are there better ways of solving this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need only one ItemsControl with template selection:

```
 <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Users}" ItemTemplate="{Binding Users.Count, Converter={StaticResource UserTemplateSelector}"/>
```

where

```
    public class UserTemplateSelector : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            int userCount = (int) value;
            if (userCount == 1)
            {
                return (DataTemplate) Application.Current.Resources["SingleUserTemplate"]; //SingleUserTemplate should be created e.g. in App.xaml
            }

            return (DataTemplate)Application.Current.Resources["MultipleUserTemplate"]; //MultipleUserTemplate should be created e.g. in App.xaml
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Great! It works so far, however because I have my `DataTemplate`s in my view (`UserControl.Resources`). So I need to find the template via accessing the view that called the converter. Is that possible?

Comment: When I try to instantiate a variable with UserManagementView class and access resources from there, the SECOND time the converter gets called I get "The name already exists in the tree: MultipleUserTemplate. Is it because I'm not accessing the view via its already created object?

Answer (score 0):

I think you only need one ItemsControl.

You can bind the Count to the Visibility of the ComboBoxes etc. via the same converter.

You probably just need something like this,

```
<ComboBox Visibility={Binding DataContext.Count, ElementName=LayoutRoot, Converter={StaticResource YourConverter}}/>
```

Comment: This is what I'm doing already, however if requirements change this will become too messy to work with.

Comment: You can always create two panels, Grid for example, one contains some controls and the other contains some other controls. And the just bind the Visibility of them. You don't need a template selector

Comment: Yup, that is what I got currently. Working out datatemplates per different criteria seems to be a better way of doing it. Also I can use it for other things.